# web.EnsureUser from a Class in SharePoint project with Custom Membership provider throws exception

Tags: sharepoint-server, membership-provider

I have a SharePoint site in 2013, configured to use a Custom Membership Provider (`inherited from MembershipProvider class`).

I have an empty SharePoint project with just a class in it. In that class, inside a method, I have used the following piece of code.

But it is throwing below exception when it encounters the `web.EnsureUser` method.

> "The specified user could not be found"

The `DLL` is deployed to `GAC` and I even tried adding a safe control entry to the SharePoint site's `web.config` file, but still, it is throwing the same exception.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    string strSiteURL = "<site URL>";
    string encUserName = EncodeUsername(userName, strSiteURL); <-- This gives the Claims encoded user name in the format i:0#.f|CustMemProvider|username
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strSiteURL))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            MembershipProvider mp = Membership.Providers["CustMemProvider"]; <-- This returns null as well.
            SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(encUserName); <-- This line throws exception.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the context this code is called from? A Web part? A workflow? A job? Something else?

Comment: It is called from another .Net class library.

Comment: Yup... but in which context at the end??

Comment: There is an MVC ASP.Net website, which calls into a class library layer from which the above code gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is called from outside the SP Web context, it probably cannot access the web.config where memberships configuration is stored. Does the web.config of your ASP.NET MVC app contain the same membership config?

Comment: No, it doesn't. It cannot also, due to some reasons. Anyway, I tried that in a sample. There also, it was throwing the same exception. This behavior happens with Custom Membership Provider only. With SqlMembershipProvider (without customization), it works fine.

Comment: Hi Evariste, Your suggestion definitely rang the bell. I am sorry for the confusion. I added the config entries in the ASP.Net MVC site and it solved the issue. Thanks a ton, Bro. Appreciate your quick turn around. I can't thank you enough. You have helped me solve a major issue. Hats-off to you. I am marking your comment as answer.